# NSArray and NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary and I have to add it to a NSArray. How can I do it?

```
NSDictionary *row = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"no_favorites", nil)], @"Address", nil];
```

If I use:

```
    aFavorite = [row allValues];
```

as sugested, if I print it I got:

```
(
"No favorites added"
)
```

What I need is:

```
  (
    {
    Address = "No favorites added";
 }
 )
```

Because I will use:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [aFavorite objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
 NSString *contentForThisRow = [dict objectForKey:@"Address"];
```

The dict value can have 1 or 2 keys.

Comment: You mean you want to convert NSDictionary to NSArray?

Comment: Yes, that what I,m looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert a Dictionary you can use it's method:

```
myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[myDic allValues]];
```

**UPDATE**

When you want to add the dic in order to retrive it and use the key to retrive the value, use `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:myDic];
```

Then retrive the dic simply by using:

```
NSDictionary *myDic = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *value = [myDic objectForKey:@"myValue"];
```

Comment: Then add the dic it self, not the value or key, please see my updated answer.

Comment: I needed NSArray, so, I createde a NSMutableArray and generate my NSArray from the NSMutableArray

Comment: There's no point in initWithArray: ... Just use [myDic allValues]

Answer (score 2):

Call `allValues` function of `NSDictionary`, it will return `NSArray` of all the values.

```
NSArray *array = [row allValues];
```

To get NSArray for keys, use,

```
NSArray *array = [row allKeys];
```

Reference link : [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

---

Well thats a basic programming logic with some string concatinations. If you want "key value pairs" then you must use NSDictionary. but if you want `Address = Something` then get all keys in one array and get all values in different array and then loop them in single loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *row = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"no_favorites", nil)], @"Address", nil];
[aFavorite addObject:row];
```

then:

```
NSDictionary* dict = [aFavorite objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSString *contentForThisRow = [dict objectForKey:@"Address"];
```

***I have an NSDictionary and I have to add it to a NSArray***

if you meant add the NSDictionary to NSArray in runtime, sorry you cant do that, NSArray is immutable.

Comment: addObject method is for NSMutableArray, I need a NSArray

Answer (score 0):

it you want to access all values then try it:-
NSArray * values = [dictionary allValues];

if access all keys try it :-
 NSArray * values = [dict allValues];